# Efficiency of JList Search

Tags: java, performance, swing, jlist, comparator

I came across some java code for doing a prefix search on a JList. Looking at it however, the meat of the algorithm is quite inefficient, using a linear search over the list for each keypress, and doing a slow case conversion within the tight loop.

I would imagine for very large amounts of data, a custom-implemented ternary search tree would be a much more efficient solution. However, if one was striving for simple code and did not have the performance requirements necessitating such complexities, are there other more simplistic ways this algorithm could be improved without necessitating significant amounts of additional code?

```
for (int i=0; i < jList1.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    String str = ((String)jList1.getModel().getElementAt(i)).toLowerCase();
    if (str.startsWith(m_key)) {
        jList1.setSelectedIndex(i); 
        jList1.ensureIndexIsVisible(i); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you measured that it caused a performance problem? JLists typically contain just a few elements (else they would not be usable), and computers execute billions of instructions per second. A GUI takes most of its time waiting for user events. Don't optimize prematurely. This code is simple, easily maintainable, and probably doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: JB Nizet: your concern about premature optimization is exactly why I wouldn't want to bother implementing and testing an entire data structure to optimize it yet! But if there would be other changes that could be made while keeping the code simple and maintainable, I'm all for better code and the exercise in thinking about balancing efficiency and simplicity

Comment: Can I ask in what this will be use ? Because if you create some sort of auto-completion algorithm you will have some wonderfull performance using a B-tree dictionnary. But it's no use for graphical representation and it's far more complex than that. By the way, if your list is sorted you can optimize your code easly.

Comment: the code that's best maintainable is the code you don't have to maintain :-) Or in other words: don't bother about core Swing details until they bite you. Its engineers are likely to have weighed the options for the typical use cases. So if they decided to leave it with a simple sequential algorithm, that can be assumed to be good enough in first approximation, until you hit an exceptional use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick change, consider

```
String str = ((String)jList1.getModel().getElementAt(i));
str.substring(1, m_key.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(m_key);
```

And for one step beyond that, your own implementation of `startsWithIgnoreCase` which should be quick and easy to write.

EDIT: This seems to be scrolling a list to the element that matches user input. You should definitely consider a more sophisticated data structure. This is done a lot, you might be able to find some efficient algorithm on the net.

Comment: In which purpose are you skiping the first character ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the quickest optimization (for time-to-code, not time-to-run), would be to sort the list and then do a binary search. You have a one-time up-front cost for the search (which, if this is used a lot, will get amortized away) and then you'll go from O(n) to O(log(n)). In my experience a binary search is relatively simple and uses the same data structures you already have.

Of course, a sorted n-tree structure will be faster algorithmically, but would require new data structures and more time in coding/testing. Decide where you want to spend your time.

Comment: +1 for a straight forward approach.  This is the answer that should be accepted as the others are minor improvements to junk.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with all answer posted here (and little bit encrypted by JB Nizet). A possible alternative to `JList` is [JTable with one Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (with or without `TableHeader`). `JTable` has a good implementation of [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: Good alternative! What is _ancrypted_?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to not browse all your list at each iteration.
You could do (n!) iterations in the list where (n) is all you need.

If the list can be sort, used partial comparaison to reach the correct answers quickly. However if you have to create your own search function it could be messy.