# Returning potential strings from a list of strings and their next chars performance

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance, algorithm

This is a question about returning efficiently strings and chars from a string array where:

1. The string in the string array starts with the user input supplied
2. The next letter of those strings as a collection of chars.

The idea is that when the user types a letter, the potential responses are displayed along with their next letters. Therefore response time is important, hence a performant algorithm is required.

E.g. If the string array contained:

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "Moose", "Mouse", "Moorhen", "Leopard", "Aardvark" };
```

If the user types in “Mo”, then “Moose”, “Mouse” and “Moorhen” should be returned  along with chars “o” and “u” for the potential next letters.

This felt like a job for LINQ, so my current implementation as a static method is (I store the output to a Suggestions object which just has properties for the 2 returned lists):

```
public static Suggestions 
GetSuggestions
    (String userInput, 
    String[] stringArray)
{
    // Get all possible strings based on the user input. This will always contain
    // values which are the same length or longer than the user input.
    IEnumerable<string> possibleStrings = stringArray.Where(x => x.StartsWith(userInput));
    IEnumerable<char> nextLetterChars = null;

    // If we have possible strings and we have some input, get the next letter(s)
    if (possibleStrings.Any() &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
    {
        // the user input contains chars, so lets find the possible next letters.
        nextLetterChars =
            possibleStrings.Select<string, char>
            (x =>
            {
                // The input is the same as the possible string so return an empty char.
                if (x == userInput)
                {
                    return '\0';
                }
                else
                {
                    // Remove the user input from the start of the possible string, then get
                    // the next character.
                    return x.Substring(userInput.Length, x.Length - userInput.Length)[0];
                }
            });
    } // End if
```

I implemented a second version which actually stored all typing combinations to a list of dictionaries; one for each word, with key on combination and value as the actual animal required, e.g.:

- Dictionary 1:
- Keys     Value
- “M”     “Moose”
- “MO     “Moose”

Etc.

- Dictionary 2:
- Keys     Value
- “M”     “Mouse”
- “MO”    “Mouse”

Etc.

Since dictionary access has an O(1) retrieval time – I thought perhaps this would be a better approach.

So for loading the dictionaries at start up:

```
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> animalCombinations = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    foreach (string animal in stringArray)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> animalCombination = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string accumulatedAnimalString = string.Empty;
        foreach (char character in animal)
        {
            accumulatedAnimalString += character;
            animalCombination[accumulatedAnimalString] = animal;
        }

        animalCombinations.Add(animalCombination);
    }
```

And then at runtime to get possible strings:

```
    // Select value entries from the list of dictionaries which contain
    // keys which match the user input and flatten into one list.
    IEnumerable<string> possibleStrings = 
        animalCombinations.SelectMany
            (animalCombination => 
                {
                    return animalCombination.Values.Where(x =>
                        animalCombination.ContainsKey(userInput));
                });
```

So questions are:

1. Which approach is better?
2. Is there a better approach to this which has better performance?
3. Are LINQ expressions expensive to process?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918542/efficiency-of-jlist-search/8919135#8919135

Comment: Are you referring to my comment? It wasn't meant to be a criticism, I thought it would be helpful. The downvote  isn't mine either.

Comment: No not your comment - I found yours and Jason's answer really helpful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which approach is better?

Probably the dictionary approach, but you'll have to profile to find out.

> Is there a better approach to this which has better performance?

**Use a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).**

> Are LINQ expressions expensive to process?

Written correctly, they add *very* little overhead to imperative versions of the same code. Since they are easier to read and maintain and write, they are usually the way to go.